# Function to set row, column, and diagonal elements in a 2D array given a cell in the array

Tags: java, matrix, set, 2d, row

I need a function with the following signature:

```
public void requiredFunction(int[][] array, int row, int column) {
    // code
}
```

The function should increment all the values in the same row, column and diagonal as `array[row][column]` (except `array[row][column]` itself).

Suppose I have the following 2D array:

```
int[][] array = {
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0
};
```

Now when I call this function with the following values:

```
requiredFunction(array, 2, 2);
```

It should convert the array to:

```
array = {
    1 0 1 0 1 0
    0 1 1 1 0 0
    1 1 0 1 1 1
    0 1 1 1 0 0
    1 0 1 0 1 0
    0 0 1 0 0 1
};
```

If you think of the array as a chess board, then the function takes the position of the queen (row and column) and increments those places on the chess board, that the queen can move to.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Comment: So, what was the question here? and [what have yout tried?](http://whathaveuyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something shorter :

```
public void requiredFunction(int[][] array, int row, int column) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; ++j) {
           if (i == column && j == row)
               continue;
           if (Math.abs(i - column) == Math.abs(j - row) ||
               i - column == 0 || j - row == 0)
               array[i][j]++;                                    
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation. :|
But thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain the logic behind the second if condition?

Comment: You calcualte the "distance" between the current indices to the target indices (row and column) if the absolute distance is equal then you are on a diagonal

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the row and column is easy, say:

```
public void requiredFunction(int[][] array, int row, int column) {
    //row
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       if(i==col)continue;
       arr[row][i]++;
    }
    //col
    for(int i=0;i<arr[0].length;i++){
       if(i==col)continue;
       arr[i][col]++;
    }
}
```

For the diagonals, it's a little bit more complicated. You can start from the selected point, and move through the diagonals one by the other. For example, this code:

```
for(int i=row+1,j=col+1;;++i,++j){
   try{
       arr[i][j]++;
   }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){//the i or j went too far from the board
       break;
   }
}
```

will increase the values which is in the right-and-down diagonal. Similar loops with `--i` instead of `++i` or `--j` instead of `++j` will do the same for the other diagonals.

**EDIT:**
As commented bellow, it is better to use regular termination condition instead of IndexOutOfBoundsException, so the loop should be:

```
for(int i = row+1, j = col+1; i <= arr.length && j <= arr[0].length; ++i, ++j){
   arr[i][j]++;
}
```

Comment: Why use `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as a termination condition, when you know the length of the array? Also you are missing brackets in your first example.

Comment: @assylias Just becouse it shorter, less possible to make stupid mistakes and some more readable (at least for me).

Comment: This is kind of a "hacky" solution. I'm actually preparing for interviews, so if I'm asked something that requires this function, I don't think it will be a good idea to give this solution.